# HAXM installed successfully, but not recognized by Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

Intel HAXM installs successfully (according to the log) both through Android Studio and directly from Intel's executable. However, Android Studio 2.1 says "HAXM is not installed" and prompts me to install it in an endless cycle (Not installed, install? Installed successfully. Not installed, install?).

Note: it worked fine in the previous version of Android Studio. Since upon upgrading it didn't recognize HAXM, I tried uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling 2.1, but it still is not recognizing the HAXM installation.

How can I get Android Studio to understand that Intel HAXM is installed?

This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Answer to a similar question is posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70642989/13026218

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running "silent_install.bat" or "intelhaxm-android.exe" resulted in a log file stating that Intel HAXM had been installed when it actually hadn't.

I was finally able to install HAXM 6.0.1 by extracting "intelhaxm-android.exe" with 7-zip and running "setup.exe" manually.

Now it's recognized by Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I only wish I found your post before digging into the BIOS settings and all that other nonsense. What a bunch of crap!

Answer (score 5):

please try to install it from here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

**or** try to uncheck >> save HAXM installer in your SDK Manager => and install it again

---

Run the HAXM installer via the path:

```
your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe
```

Take a look at this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying both of your suggestions, Android Studio still claims that HAXM is not installed (despite the installer saying that it installed successfully).

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, but it still doesn't recognize HAXM. Note that the latest version of Intel HAXM is named intelhaxm-android.exe and executing it doesn't display an install wizard like the one in the video you linked to. It creates a haxm_silent_run.log file that contains the text, "Intel HAXM installed successfully!" But Android Studio still says it's not installed.

Answer (score 4):

The link to the youtube from **[mounir elfassi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494799/mounir-elfassi)** answer on this problem worked for me in 2021.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs

In this tutorial, He go to the HAXM file location where it is already downloaded by android studio and installs it manually.

I tried the same method and my problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. I have to install HAXM manually.

Comment: Thanks... This solution from the video worked for me. I had to install HAXM manually. Then I changed the Virtual Device RAM allocation to the same size of the HAXM allocated RAM size. 1024 MB in my own case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install manually by going to file path -

> ~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Sometimes the *HaxmSetup.exe* does not install and shows an error"*The system requirements are not satisfied*".

This error can have multiple reasons,

- Hyper-V is enabled.
- Virtualisation is disabled.
- ...

I found the [solution here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/haxm-installation-failed-install-intel-haxm-in-windows/)

For my device the virtualization was disabled, and it can be easily checked
by going to task manager and then under performance tab below the CPU utilization graph.

Then you have to enable it by going into BIOS setting of your device. It is different for every device so it is better you search where can you find virtualization settings for your device.

Comment: If you are using a link for your answer, consider explaining the answer in the link in your own words a little more. In case the link gets broken or unavailable for some reason, your answer will still be accessible in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:
1- going to my android sdk.
2- open 'extras' file then 'intel then 'Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager'.
3- Finally 'haxm-7.6.5-setup' to setup manually.
this should work will with you as happened with me.

Answer (score 0):

For any reader/developer going through same problem with android studio hedgehog and xham installer issue, I will suggest checking the android sdk location and clicking on extra folder inside where you might find xham installer setup whose version could be lower than the one you are trying to install. Went thru same problem and this thing worked. Hope it will work for anyone going with same issue too. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above doesn't work with me Until I **DISABLED WINDOWS DEFENDER** or exclude the SDK and project folder from realtime scanning.