# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD, but I already installed it

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sdk, haxm

I've been looking online for this and it seems like no one has the same problem as I have. I just downloaded Android Studio to start learning Kotlin and after following Google's tutorial steps I get this message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwW3T.png)

After that I hit ok to Install the HAXM thing and it says successful but It goes back to the same message of HAXM needs to be installed. I tried SDK manager --> SDK tools --> Intel x86 Emmulator Accelerator (turn on), It didnt work. Someone help, please

Comment: I had same problem I downloaded HAXM and then installed it manually. Problem is that when you download sdk and install it, in some cases it didn't install it correctly. So what should you do? As I said just download HAXM from internet and install it by your self and manually Let me know if you solve it

Comment: Do you have an intel cpu or amd one?

Answer (score 4):

Go to your SDK directory:

`(C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally)`.

In this directory, go to:

`extras → Intel → Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` and run the file named `"haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe"`.

After you install, android studio will detect it. If not, restart android studio.

Comment: This one solved the problem! Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

What I did was I opened the *SDK Manager* > *SDK Tools* tab and checked *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)*, 7.6.5 and installed.

In the window displaying the installation progress, click on the *Show details* button and you'll see a log, not quite long. At some point you'll come accross something like "Path for download "*C:\Users<YOUR_USER>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager*"). In my case it said that this folder already existed, so it was downloding it to folder *...\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2* instead.

Once it's done, go to that folder and you should find a file named "haxm-7.6.5-setup". Run it and it will install HAXM. Now you'll be able to run your emulator, even if the message "HAXM is not installed" keeps appearing.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to install HAXM via Android Studio as described above. Android Studio reported version 7.6.5 was available. However I had installed a newer version (7.8.0) manually.

The emulator would not recognize the newer, manually installed HAXM. All attempts to install HAXM via the Studio would fail, and no installation file was present in the Android/sdk/extras/intel folder.

This is what I did:

(1) Uninstall HAXM via Windows.
Settings>Apps>Program and Features>Turn Windows features on or off (search for Intel).

(2) Install HAXM inisde Android Studio via the SDK Manager.

Comment: Is this answer relevant for someone with a CPU that is't an intel one?